# OS Ticket Open Ticket CSRF Token Dump Error

Tags: osticket

When i open new ticket in OS Ticket System, after ticket submission dump the array in the top of the page.
Error shown below.
[Click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5f9B.png)

Update

Error in text form:

Array ( [**CSRFToken**] => a56c08a9f49842de2ab3fc8e02d13ca2921d5f49 [a] => open [695fbbb799cdbbc2] => usman.saif22@gmail.com [ecf6c52d42557ef0] => M Usman [fec356fce5ea2de9] => [fec356fce5ea2de9-ext] => [topicId] => 2 [83163d48527225db] => Testing [message] => Testing [draft_id] => [emailId] => 0 [deptId] => 0 [cannedattachments] => Array ( ) )

This error occur when open new ticket, even ticket is successfully opened. But, shown this error when user open ticket.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error in text form? It will be easier to read and for other users to search.

Comment: Array ( [__CSRFToken__] => a56c08a9f49842de2ab3fc8e02d13ca2921d5f49 [a] => open [695fbbb799cdbbc2] => usman.saif22@gmail.com [ecf6c52d42557ef0] => M Usman [fec356fce5ea2de9] => [fec356fce5ea2de9-ext] => [topicId] => 2 [83163d48527225db] => Testing [message] => Testing [draft_id] => [emailId] => 0 [deptId] => 0 [cannedattachments] => Array ( ) )